# findAndModify() works, but equivalent update() doesn't?

Tags: mongodb

> Prexisting data:
>   {   "posts" : [ { "a" : { "t" : 2}} ] }
>
> > > db.users.findAndModify({ query:{"posts.a": {"$exists" : true} }, update:{"$push" : {"posts.$.a.test": {"d" : 2}}}  })
>
> Data after command: {"posts" : [ { "a" : { "t" : 2,
>   "test" : [ { "d" : 2 } ] } } ] }

That is correct. However the exact same command does not work as update():

```
> db.users.update({{"posts.a": {"$exists" : true} }, 
                   {"$push" : {"posts.$.a.test": {"d" : 2}}}, true, false })
```

> Output: Thu Nov 24 12:07:02 SyntaxError: invalid property id (shell):1

Why not?

Comment: It's update({find}, {update}, upsert, multi) not update({{find}, {update}}, upsert, multi)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a syntax error to me: the update method takes four arguments, two objects and two booleans, not just one object. So,

```
db.users.update({{"posts.a": {"$exists" : true} }, 
                {"$push" : {"posts.$.a.test": {"d" : 2}}}, true, false })
```

should read

```
db.users.update({"posts.a": {"$exists" : true} }, 
                {"$push" : {"posts.$.a.test": {"d" : 2}}}, true, false)
```